# Want Map function to apply over sum of terms but not product

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, map

For a given function `F`, if I use `Map[F,a+b+c d]`, Mathematica returns, as desired:

> F[a]+F[b]+F[c d] ;

However, for `Map[F, c d]` it gives

> F[c] F[d]

-- this I don't want.

I need `Map[F,c d]=F[c d]` only, i.e., I need Map to distribute over sum (`Plus`), but not over product (`Times`). Is it possible in some way?

Comment: try [Distribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html)?( E.g., `Distribute[F[a + b + c d]]` and `Distribute[F[c d]]`.)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not a satisfactory answer, but you'll need to provide more context. The short answer is, "yes":

```
Map[F, c d, {0}]
(* F[c d] *)
```

But I'm suspicious that this isn't what you want, because it doesn't generalize well. For example, going back to your first input:

```
Map[F, a + b + c d, {0}]
(* F[a + b + c d] *)
```

So, what we really need is to understand what your semantics are. If you want a sort of "universal" solution, then you'll need to describe what's "universal" about your inputs. Or maybe that doesn't matter, and this ad hoc approach is fine. I'd need more info.

#### Update

Actually, I guess you did provide semantics and I was over-indexing on Map. Yeah, distributing over sums but not products is sort of the definition of `Distribute` per @kglr's comment.