# Optimal way of defining sums-linear function

Tags: functions, summation

I asked on a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300411/97982) how to define a function which satisfies $f[x+y]=f[x]+f[y]$ and then define $f[x]$ on monomials.  The problem with this is that it involves a lot of iterations when we consider $f[x_1+x_2+...+x_n]$. For example :

```
f[a_ + b_] := Module[{}, Print["Hello"]; Return[f[a] + f[b]];]
f[a_] := 1
f[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5]
```

returns

> Hello 
> Hello 
> Hello 
> Hello 
> 5

It passes 4 times through the first definition.
However now I have very bigs sums, and my code stops with RecursionLimit errors, so I want a better solution that avoids iterating too much. How to define directly $f[x_1+x_2+...+x_n] = f[x_1]+...+f[x_n]$ for an arbitrary sum ?

Concretely I have a huge sum of 104 MB memory size, and I want to apply a function to each term in this sum. How to do it most efficiently ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want Map function to apply over sum of terms but not product](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295404/want-map-function-to-apply-over-sum-of-terms-but-not-product) Namely, just use `Distribute` or `Map`.

Comment: As @Domen indicated: `f[arg_Plus] := f /@ arg`